# confused about basic find and replace app

Tags: php

I am trying to do a find and replace applicaiton the problem is that after cliked submit button all the  text fields gets clean  nothing displays on the screen What am i doing wrong

```
<?php
$offset=0;
if(isset($_POST['text'] ) && isset($_POST['searchfor']) && isset($_POST['replacewith'])){
    $text=$_POST['text'];
    $search=$_POST['searchfor'];
    $replace=$_POST['replacewith'];
    $searchLength=strlen($search);
    if(!empty($text) && !empty($search) &&!empty($replace)){
        while ($strpos= strpos($text,$search,$offset)){
            echo $offset=$strpos+$searchLength;
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('errorrrr')</script>";
    }
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
Search For:<br>
<input type="text" name="searchfor"><br>
ReplaceWith<br>
<input type="text"name="replacewith"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Fr..."></>
</form>
```

Comment: That is because you have to put the data into the HTML if you want to see it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your form, you decided to submit to the same page.
Doing this, the page is obviously fully reloaded when submitted. Hence it is normal that what you typed in has disappeared.

If you want to see it again, you have to display you variables in the HTML code.

For example:

```
<?php    
    $myVar = "";
    if(isset($_POST['myVar']){
        $myVar = $_POST['myVar'];
    }
?>
    <form>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $myVar;?>"/>
    </form>
```

NB: I encourage you to filter the user entry.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

there is problems in your code : 
1 - `echo $offset=$strpos+$searchLength;` the echo can't be used in this format. insted use `echo $offset;` in next line for seeing offset values.

2 - if the text be like 'amir love persepolis' and search for 'amir' to replace it with 'all men's' you will have another issue, because you will have while ( 0 ) situation. think about this too!